# I ran out of quotation marks when assigning an onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

My code:

`<a href="#" onclick="$('#s input[name='reset']').click(); return false;">RESET</a>`

Apparently as you can see I can't use `'` nor `"` at the part `[name=` as either one will end the previous quotation mark of the same type.

Need some help. One way would be to define a function and have onclick trigger the function, but I'm hoping to get the code (it's just 1 line) assigned to onclick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you **could** use escaped `\'` or `\"` but the best solution at all is **just not to use those inline event handlers**.

```
$('a').bind('click', function(e){
   $('input[name=reset]').trigger('click');
});
```

Obviously, this would affect all anchors. So a class or an ID would be advisable.

Comment: Alright thanks. I figured out almost as soon as I posted, and I'm (pleasantly) surprised to see 3 answers already. :D

Comment: BTW what's the difference between using the `bind()` and `click(function() {});`? And why `function(e)`? Why not other letters?

Comment: there is no difference, `click()` is a shortcut for `.bind('click',..)` philosophical question :)

Comment: Wanted to set your answer as accepted answer just now, but I had to wait 1 hour :)

Comment: Just FYI for anyone reading this later: if you want to prevent the default action on the hyperlink (like the OP seemed to), you'd need to insert either `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();` to the snippet given in the answer.